# Whats wrong with this simple c program?

Tags: c

I want to know why this program, that i create just for practice, don't works properly. The program asks for 5 numbers that put in an array called "array". There are also 2 VOID functions, one for get the numbers, that uses a for cicle and scanf instruction , and another, that has to print the 5 numbers in the array. The problem is that the numbers printed are only the firsts 4. What's wrong? 
P.S. Sorry for my ignorance but i'm a beginner. Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
array_print(int array[],size_t size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%i ",array[i]);
    }
}

void
get_num(int array[],size_t size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%i",&array[i]);
    }
}

int
main(){
    int array[5];
    size_t size;
    size=sizeof(int);
    printf("Insert 5 numbers: ");
    get_num(array,size);
    array_print(array,size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you check this one -> size=sizeof(int); -> size=sizeof(array);

Comment: Should be `size=sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);`

Comment: `array` contains several `int`s. while you are doing `sizeof(int)` - e.g get the size of just one `int`. Furthermore - size of int or size of array is useless to you! What you need is count of number of ints in the array. Rename your `size` to `count` and use suggestion from Lundin

Answer (score 6):

In the environment where you run the program `sizeof(int)` is equal to `4`.

The size of the array can be calculated like

```
size = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( int );
```

Take into account the type of the value returned by the operator `sizeof` is `size_t`. So it would be better to use this type for the size of the array.

Also you could introduce a manifest constant for number `5`. As for example

```
#define N 5
```

and declare the array like

```
int array[N];
```

Or if the compiler supports variable length arrays you could write

```
int main( void )
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int array[N];

    //...
```

Comment: and if it doesn't, use `#define size 5`  (you should really use SIZE)

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of the compiler in which you're executing your code is 32bit so the size of int is 32bits = 4 bytes.

`size = sizeof(int)`
will return 
`size = 4`
and you will be only able to enter four values.

Comment: See @Lundin's comment for a solution.